# How to design hash table efficiently for storing big word sequence?

Tags: data-structures

I want to find top K frequent words from a big word sequence. Please help me to design a efficient hash table for this

Answer (score 0):

Split your string into an array of strings by spaces or whatever delimiters and then put it into a HashMultiset

then you can simply get your counts for each word.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a min heap of size `k` here instead of a hash table. Just add words to the heap with their respective length - once you have k+1 items in the heap, remove the minimum item and reheapify. Overall effort will be O(n*log(k)) and you will need O(k) extra space (to maintain the heap).